# iPhone/iPad app using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

With the availability of keyboards for iPads and iPhones, it makes sense to add keyboard shortcuts to apps now.

Is it possible to do this in an app? What are the relevant APIs?

Answer (score 2):

While this question is fairly old, Apple has added support for keyboard specific shortcuts in iOS 7.  Check out the [UIKeyCommand class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIKeyCommand) in the UIKit Framework for special support for hardware keyboard shortcuts.  The high level steps for us are:

1. Use the static `keyCommandWithInput:modifierFlags:action:` method on the `UIKeyCommand` class to create an instance of the `UIKeyCommand` for the specified keys with modifiers.  Note that any keyboard shortcuts handled by the system (like Command-C for copy) will not work.  You will also pass an action selector that will be called when the keyboard shortcut is used
2. Associate this newly created `UIKeyCommand` with your responder object(s) by returning them from the responder object's `keyCommand` property.
3. When the keys are pressed, your selector will be called.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no special API for keyboard events or specific key stroke events like you would get on the desktop. But I believe in iOS 3.2 you have a lot more access to the keyboard, and you may be able to get access to those touch events. I'm not sure how an external keyboard would factor into that though. It does seem that this is something Apple hasn't really thought of, or has decided isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, but if your application's top-level view creates a hidden text view then calls "`[textView becomeFirstResponder];`" then responded to `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification`s you might be able to pick up the control keys entered in the text field.  The downside there is that you'd have to suppress the keyboard popping up if no external keyboard is attached and you don't want to offer any direct text input.

Comment: control characters are not passed by that protocol. wouldn't make sense, either. keeping the keyboard down doesn't work without private api.