# Add external keyboard shortcut for iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, external

I'd love to know if there's a way to support external keyboard events on an iPad app? It would make a lot of sense for my app to support Command-(a number key) to switch between tabs.

I've been looking for a tutorial online but so far haven't found any..

Comment: Did you find out anything about this?

Comment: it seems that there's no way to do this as of now, unfortunately

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349050/iphone-ipad-app-using-keyboard-shortcuts/19864670

Comment: Ask Apple. I'm serious. :)

Comment: Also, ask this on http://superuser.com/